# Divisor of a singular cone

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I have the cone
$$X=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{A}^3 \mid z^2=xy\}$$

and the regular function $f=x\in\mathscr{O}_X$. I don't understand why the Weil Divisor associated to $f$ is $\mathrm{div}(f)=2L$ where $L\subset X$ is the line defined by equations $x=z=0$. I don't know what is the general method to find a divisor because I'm new in algebraic geometry. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome new contributor. This question is a little light on context right now - for instance: do you know the general procedure for finding the Weil divisor associated to a function, and the issue is the computation, or are you unaware of the procedure in general? Please improve your question with an [edit] to make it clearer what you know and where you're stuck. See [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R = k[x,y,z] / ( z^2 - xy)$, and $p = (x, z)$. Then, $m_p^2 \subseteq R_p$ is generated by $(x,z)^2 = (x^2, xz, z^2) = (x^2, xz,xy)$. Since $y$ is invertible in $R_p$, and $xy \in (x,z)^2$, $x \in m_p^2$.

Now consider $m_p^3 = (x) * (x, z) = (x^2, xz)$. This time, $x$ is not in $m_p^3$. Therefore , the valuation of $x$ at $p$ is $2$.

Comment: Sorry, I don´t understand this answer. I don´t know the general method to find a divisor of a function, so I would appreciate a best explanation.

Comment: To find the divisor of $f \in K(X)^*$ at a codimension 1 point $p$, note that $O_{X, p}$ is a discrete valuation ring and $Quot(O_{X, p}) = K(X)$, where $Quot$ denotes field of fractions. Therefore, $f$ corresponds to $a/b \in Quot(O_{X, p})$, and then just take $val_p(a) - val_p(b)$.